# Add task in between two include directives in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have something like this in my `play.yml`

```
---
- include: containers-deploy.yml
- include: db-deploy.yml
```

There is a need to install `firewalld` in between those two includes but we cannot modify the above `yml` files

Have tried the following two approaches.

-
trying to include a task in between these two

```
---
- include: containers-deploy.yml
- task:
    name: install firewalld
    yum:
      name: firewalld
      state: installed
- include: db-deploy.yml
```

which throws an `ERROR! 'task' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

other one I tried was to do a

```
---
- include: containers-deploy.yml
- include: install-firewalld.yml
- include: db-deploy.yml
```

where `install-firewalld.yml` would include

```
---
- name: Install firewalld
  yum: 
    name: firewalld
    state: installed
```

This one throws a `ERROR! 'yum' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

What should be the approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute a task without being in a Play.

You should do something like that :

```
- include: containers-deploy.yml
- hosts: your-target-host 
  tasks:
    - name: install firewalld
      yum:
        name: firewalld
        state: installed
- include: db-deploy.yml
```